# How to pass callback function if the function to be passed is in the jquery widget?

Tags: jquery

This is my widget.

```
$.custom("custom.myWidget", function(){

_create: function() {

   this._main();
},

_main: function(){

_callFunction(_passMe, par1, par2);

},
_passMe: function(par1, par2) {

...
....

},

_callFunction: function(callbackFunction, par1, par2) {

....
...
callbackFunction(par1, par2);

}

});
```

So what I need to do is to run _passMe function inside callbackFunction. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, pass like this

```
this._passMe.bind(this)
```

For an instance,

```
_callFunction: function(callbackFunction, par1, par2) {

....
...
callbackFunction(par1, par2, this._passMe.bind(this));

}
```

You are passing here the reference to the `_paasMe` function